# Displaying a Qlik Sence Dashboard in SharePoint SPFx React Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, react

I want to create a SharePoint Online SPFx web part (using React) and want to embed QlickSence Dashboard in that web part.

I am working with `iframe`, is there a better way of embedding using react?

Comment: I am having same requirement and able to acheive it by iframe in spfx solution, however that is performance killer. I tried to use qlik sense compatiblity API but having few issues in dynamically loading qlik module within SPFx. Did you get any success or what path you choosen, Any help is highly appreciated !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to embed something on SharePoint online page using `iframe`, you can use SharePoint out of the box [Embed web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-content-to-your-page-using-the-embed-web-part-721f3b2f-437f-45ef-ac4e-df29dba74de8).

And if you want to achieve this using SPFx react only, you should be able to use `iframe` without any problem --> I think this is the best way to embed external pages using SPFx react.

**Similar threads**:

1. [How to embed Qlik Sense Visualizations into O365 SharePoint](https://community.qlik.com/t5/Integration-Extension-APIs/How-to-embed-Qlik-Sense-Visualizations-into-O365-SharePoint/td-p/78692)
2. [Integrating qlik sense with Sharepoint](https://community.qlik.com/t5/New-to-Qlik-Sense/Integrating-qlik-sense-with-Sharepoint/td-p/710713)
3. [Qlik Sense Enterprise SaaS: How to embed a chart in an iFrame](https://community.qlik.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/Qlik-Sense-Enterprise-SaaS-How-to-embed-a-chart-in-an-iFrame/ta-p/1711503)